# How do I add specular highlights using a single color in Blender Internal?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I think I have tried every possible combination of settings and the closest I've come to what I need is this:
[image]

See those areas that are white? I need to them to be #FFEBBD, or any color that I choose for a specific material. I've done a ton of experimenting which only resulted in complete garbage or some blended specular shading adding a dozen extra colors to my palette (which I must avoid).

Here are the settings I used to achieve those white speculars:
[image]

Now if only someone could tell me what I need to do to have a color of my choosing show up there instead of that white. And yes. I've tried changing the Specular color. And the ramp colors. And I've tried every combination of Input and Blend.

edit:

here's the material preview

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the material preview look like?

Comment: Just added a pic of it to the original post.

Comment: What does it look like if you change the white specular highlight? (I admit, just from the color ramp it looks like it shouldn't be white, but it still is.)

Comment: Exactly the same. Added picture to show you. Now, I found a slight workaround until I can find a solution, but it's still not ideal. I can use the Toon Shader to get a non-white color (but still not my color of choice) which I can then replace with my desired color in gimp (which I couldn't do with white, since different materials will need different spec colors and if they're all white I can't differentiate between them with the color select tool) So far I don't really like the spec placement with Toon, but I'm going to play with it some more.

Comment: That is a really weird problem. Just a shot in the dark here—but I see your diffuse color is still white (at least from the first picture), what does changing that do?

Comment: Changing the diffuse color would wreck the color ramp for the diffuse. But I stumbled on something. Changing the color on the specular ramp to green gives me a uniform color very close to the one I want. I think it's just this particular combination of colors that won't play nice, because I rendered some grass using this same material setup, but with greens, and everything worked.

Comment: Green worked? Wacky. Glad you figured it out.